# Set max removal of Redux-Form field from Index - field validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

https://codesandbox.io/s/zoojymzyp

My example above has the ability to push and remove fields to update json to send. The form pre-populates fields that can be written over or deleted. However, I want there to be 1 field left as a minimum - e.g. you cant remove all fields there has to be at least one field - at the minute I can remove all until there are no inputs.

```
class renderForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let {
            fields,
            label
        } = this.props;
        const removeName = (index) => {
            fields = fields.remove(index);
        }
        return ( <
            div >
            <
            div variant = "fab"
            color = "primary"
            className = "jr-fab-btn"
            aria - label = "add"
            onClick = {
                () => fields.push()
            } >
            ADD <
            /div>

            {
                fields.map((newIntel, index) => {
                    console.log("newIntel", newIntel, index);
                    return ( <
                        div >
                        <
                        Field name = {
                            newIntel
                        }
                        key = {
                            index
                        }
                        label = {
                            label
                        }
                        placeholder = {
                            label
                        }
                        component = {
                            renderTextArea
                        }
                        /> <
                        p variant = "fab"
                        color = "primary"
                        style = {
                            {
                                'cursor': 'pointer'
                            }
                        }
                        className = "jr-fab-btn"
                        aria - label = "add"
                        onClick = {
                            () => removeName(index)
                        } >
                        REMOVE <
                        /p> <
                        /div>
                    );
                })
            } <
            /div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly.

Comment: Change your remove to `const removeName = index => {
      if(fields.length === 1){
        alert('can not remove')
      }else{
      fields = fields.remove(index);
      }
    };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @just-codes answer in comments:

```
  const removeName = (index) => {
    {fields.length === 1 ? null : fields = fields.remove(index)}
  }
```

This was exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a contrived example that shows one way of doing this.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: []
  };

  addItem = () => {
    const { items } = this.state;
    items.push("item");
    this.setState({ items });
  };

  removeItem = () => {
    const { items } = this.state;
    if (items.length > 1) {
      items.pop("item");
    }

    this.setState({ items });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add</button>
        <button onClick={this.removeItem}>Remove</button>
        <ul>
          {this.state.items.map(i => (
            <li>{i}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Basically you can modify your removal function to do nothing if there's only one item left. CodeSandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zk26k6v2z3).